# We don't have any [friends]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The tag [friends](/questions/tagged/friends) (8 non-deleted questions, no tag wiki) is one of those useless meta tags. It seems to refer to several different concepts:

- Adding some kind of social media-style 'friends list' to the system
- Referring friends to Stack Exchange
- Concerns over sanctions when someone votes on a post belonging to a 'friend'
- A question seeking friends ([really!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5432/336163)).

It was brought to my attention few days ago by someone posting a [question asking for dating advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339513/336163) (+10k only).

Do we really need this tag?

Comment: I don't need friends, I have the Internet... :D

Comment: So... I'll not be there for you?

Comment: @Machavity *"Your mother warned you there'd be days like these"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this had approval for awhile, so I went ahead and removed this tag from the 6 questions (4 of which are dupe-closed) that had it.

I'm sorry to say, but I made no [friends](/questions/tagged/friends) in the process. It was a rather lonely process, actually.

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9f/8d/5d/9f8d5d463f7b67c2be23d31791384254.jpg :)

Comment: Fun fact: I had a friend called NoFriends on a forum I was member for 10 years or so.

Answer (score 13):

Seems legit, unless someone has a great reason we should keep the tag, so give it a week then we might be able to get rid of the tag, and some of the questions too.